# How can I add multiple hyperlinks into a discord.py Embed?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making an about command for my discord bot and I want to implement multiple hyperlinks into the title, but you can only use one title as you can't duplicate keyword arguments. If I add more to the title it will just go to the same url. Here is what I envision:

**Invite BOTNAME** (directs to bot invite link) | **Website** (directs to discord bot website)

Is there any way possible to do this within the ***title*** argument within the `myEmbed = discord.Embed(title=" ")` or would it have to be done in a field or footer?

Comment: Does `title` accept markdown, or is it expecting plain text? Why are you trying to do this in the title and not just embed fields?

Comment: do you want the [Invite BOTNAME](https://www.youtube.com/) to be a hyper link or just have a link next to it like Invite BOTNAME https://www.youtube.com/  | Website https://www.youtube.com/

Comment: @yotamrec the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
myembed = discord.Embed(title="[Invite](link) | ...")
```

This also works with descriptions.

A small advice for the next time, search for `discord.py hyperlinks embed` on Google. I'm sure you'll find something ;)

EDIT: Small correction, it's not working with titles, it works with descriptions and values in fields

Answer (score 0):

this does work on the title! When you have it like (title = (),description = () just add another "," and add URL = (link) like this

title = (), description = (), url = (link)